# How integrate wordpress custom posts to new firebase entries?

Tags: ios, wordpress, firebase

I currently have a wordpress website for my company whats serves for show a catalog of our products.

Recently i develop a iOS app for company salesmen with firebase as backend to serve as database for products catalog.

But now i have to different sources for same kind of data. I was wondering how can i use wordpress admin to generate new firebase entries while i add new wordpress posts.

There is any service that integrate the databases or some functions that i can perform to create new firebase entry while i create a new wordpress post?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this step you need to add a function at your function.php file (on your wordpress theme) which will be awakened when a new Post will be created

```
function newPostCreated(){
   $post_id = $post->ID;
   // from here send the data to firebase 
}

add_action( 'draft_to_publish', 'newPostCreated' );
```

You can find php code to interact with Firebase here -> https://gist.github.com/krhoyt/655a892d315167194516

---

The easy alternative to this system could be Zapier.com

You can attach a Zap on Wordpress which retrieve the last post and, after that, you can add an Action to send the data on Firebase

Hope this help you!

Comment: Hi Giuseppe, great solution! I will try to create a function to achieve this with the method you recommend. Thank!